# How to delete all custom resources of a kind in k8s cluster (all namespaces) using client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I'm trying to delete resources of a particular kind in a k8s cluster using client-go.

I'm using this code but it requires a specific namespace to be declared, but i want to delete this resource in all namespaces.

```
    u.SetName("test")
    u.SetNamespace(v1.NamespaceAll)
    u.SetGroupVersionKind(schema.GroupVersionKind{
        Group:   "group",
        Kind:    "kind",
        Version: "v1",
    })
    err := k8sClient.Delete(context.TODO(), u)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return err
    }
```

Found the example here - https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client
but it doesn't mention anything about all namespaces.
Could someone plz provide a way to figure this out.

NOTE:
This is custom resource. not default kind such as pod or deployment etc

Comment: Couldn't you just use the above code, but iterate over all namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `List` method to get a list of all resources in `all namespaces` and then loop through the list and delete each resource using the `Delete` method.

```js
cr := &v1alpha1.CustomResource{}

// Get a list of all instances of your custom resource in all namespaces
listOpts := []client.ListOption{
    client.InNamespace(v1.NamespaceAll),
}

err := k8sClient.List(context.Background(), cr, listOpts...)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

// Loop through the list and delete each instance of your custom resource
for _, item := range cr.Items {
    err = k8sClient.Delete(context.Background(), &item)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fetching mappings and deleting them one by one, you can use **DeleteAllOf**

```
err := k8sClient.DeleteAllOf(ctx, &v1alpha1.CustomResource{}, client.InNamespace(v1.NamespaceAll))
```